# How can I condition an autoregressive vector model given past observations?

Tags: forecasting, predictive-models, econometrics, conditional-probability, vector-autoregression

I'm trying to predict the scores of a soccer team in the next match using a VAR (Vector Autoregression Model). So my first attempt was to define the model as it follows:

$$g_{1,t}=\alpha_{1}+\beta_{11}\cdot g_{1,t-1}+\beta_{12}\cdot g_{2,t-2}+u_{t}$$

$$g_{2,t}=\alpha_{1}+\beta_{21}\cdot g_{1,t-1}+\beta_{22}\cdot g_{2,t-2}+v_{t}$$

Where,

$g_{i,t}$: goals difference of team $i$ in game $t$ (
scored goals - goals against).

---

**Why this model?**

I think that the difference in past goals that a team obtained is a good measure of how well the team is performing in terms of attack and defense, in the same way the goal difference of the rival team indicates how well the rival team is performing which could affect the team's ability to score goals and deffend against them. I also think that these goals could have a lagging effect which decreases as the team plays more games.

---

**BACK TO THE PROBLEM**

So imagine that we have this same model with more lags. So, imagine that this 2 teams already have played 5 games. And that our model predict the scores of each of them as:

$$g_{A,t}=5$$
$$g_{B,t}=2$$

We could think that team A have more chances of winning against team B. But, assume that Team A played games against easier rivals and Team B played games against more difficult rivals. I was asking myself:

1. "How can I take into account the fact that team A played with easier rivals in the model"?
2. "How can I measure the level of difficulty that a team represents?"

**Basically,  How can I condition the model given the past observations?**